# How to get the names of all the vaults in Autodesk Vault Professional 2014?

Tags: c#, autodesk

I have just started learning the Vault API. I have just managed to get a login window running. Now I want to get the names of all the vaults from the login dropdown. Is it possible? and if it is can someone tell me what to search on google for this?
Also I would like some Vault tutorial links if anyone knows any.

Any help is appreciated. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on the CodeProject cross post - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/753540/How-to-get-the-names-of-all-the-vaults-in-Autodesk